# How can I check for generic type in Kotlin

Tags: generic-programming, kotlin

I'm trying to test for a generic type in Kotlin.

```
if (value is Map<String, Any>) { ... }
```

But the compiler complains with

> Cannot check for instance of erased type: jet.Map

The check with a normal type works well.

```
if (value is String) { ... }
```

Kotlin 0.4.68 is used.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The problem is that type arguments are erased, so you can't check against the full type Map, because at runtime there's no information about those String and Any.

To work around this, use wildcards:

```
if (value is Map<*, *>) {...}
```

Comment: Great! That perfectly works! I just got confused by the example in the documentation: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Type+casts

Comment: What if you actually want to check that something is a `Collection<String>` to make it auto cast?

Comment: I have snippet like this `if (it.getSerializable(ARG_PARAMS) is HashMap<*, *>) {it.getSerializable(ARG_PARAMS) as HashMap<String, String>} else null`. So basically it's gonna try to cast `HashMap<String, Integer>` to `HashMap<String, String>` if I'm checking against generic type. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FARID Yes, it will, and this kind of cast is not safe

Answer (score 31):

I think this is more appropriate way

```
inline fun <reified T> tryCast(instance: Any?, block: T.() -> Unit) {
    if (instance is T) {
        block(instance)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
// myVar is nullable
tryCast<MyType>(myVar) {
    // todo with this e.g.
    this.canDoSomething()
}
```

**Another shorter approach**

```
inline fun <reified T> Any?.tryCast(block: T.() -> Unit) {
    if (this is T) {
        block()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
// myVar is nullable
myVar.tryCast<MyType> {
    // todo with this e.g.
    this.canDoSomething()
}
```

Comment: Why something like this is not available directly in kotlin stdlib :-(

Comment: Isn't `something as? String` the same? Note the question mark after `as`?

Comment: @DaliborFilus nope. This is about Generics and erased types during runtime. If you don´t have to deal with Generics, you can just use `as?`, correct.

Answer (score 21):

JVM removes the generic type information. But Kotlin has reified generics. If you have a generic type T, you can mark type parameter T of an inline function as reified so it will be able to check it at runtime.

So you can do:

```
inline fun <reified T> checkType(obj: Object, contract: T) {
  if (obj is T) {
    // object implements the contract type T
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how to call `checkType()`?  I'm not sure what to pass for the second argument.

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky `checkType(myMapOfStrings, Map<String, Any>)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
// Use this value if it is of type T, or else use defaultValue
inline fun <reified T> Any?.useIfTypeOrDefault(defaultValue: T) = 
    if (this is T) this else defaultValue
```

Usage (kotest):

```
val map = mapOf("foo" to listOf("cheese"), "bar" to 666)

map["foo"].useIfTypeOrDefault<List<String>>(emptyList()).firstOrNull() shouldBe "cheese"
map["bar"].useIfTypeOrDefault<List<String>>(emptyList()).firstOrNull() shouldBe null

map["foo"].useIfTypeOrDefault<Number>(-1) shouldBe -1
map["bar"].useIfTypeOrDefault<Number>(-1) shouldBe 666
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give a workaround solution but I think its clean, kind of

```
try{
  (value as Map<String,Any>?)?.let { castedValue ->
     doYourStuffHere() //using castedValue
  }
}catch(e: Exception){
  valueIsNotOfType() //Map<String,Any>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the solution above with `tryCast<Array<String?>>` and, I guess, in my specific task in listing with many castings involved it was no so great idea, because it was slowing the performance drastically.

This is the solution I did finally - manually check the entries and call methods, like this:

```
 fun foo() {
    val map: Map<String?, Any?> = mapOf()
    map.forEach { entry ->
        when (entry.value) {
            is String -> {
                doSomeWork(entry.key, entry.value as String)
            }
            is Array<*> -> {
                doSomeWork(entry.key, (entry.value as? Array<*>)?.map {
                    if (it is String) {
                        it
                    } else null
                }?.toList())
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun doSomeWork(key: String?, value: String) {

}
private fun doSomeWork(key: String?, values: List<String?>?) {

}
```