# How can I check for array type (not generic type) in Kotlin

Tags: java, casting, kotlin

I have a java code like this:

```
String getData(Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof String[])
    {
        String[] arr = (String[]) obj;
        if (arr.length > 0)
        {
            return arr[0];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

How should I convert this code into Kotlin?
I have tried automatic Java to Kotlin conversion, and this was the result:

```
fun getData(obj:Any):String {
    if (obj is Array<String>)
    {
        val arr = obj as Array<String>
        if (arr.size > 0)
        {
            return arr[0]
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

This is the error I've got from the kotlin compiler:

> Can not check for instance of erased type: Array<String>

I thought that type erasure applies only for generic types, and not simple, strongly typed Java arrays. How should I properly check for component type of the passed array instance?

**EDIT**

This question differs from generic type checking questions, because Java arrays **are not** generic types, and usual Kotlin type checks using the *is* operator cause compile time error.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check for generic type in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154463/how-can-i-check-for-generic-type-in-kotlin)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it's different because `String[]` is not a generic type in Java.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The correct way to handle this (as of Kotlin 1.2) is to use the [`isArrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/is-array-of.html) function:

```
fun getData(x: Any): String? {
    if (x is Array<*> && x.isArrayOf<String>()) {
        return x[0] as String
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't knew about this `isArrayOf` function

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind that there are also arrays for basic types such as `ByteArray` which is not the same as `Array<Byte>`. For the basic type you can check with e.g. `is ByteArray`

Comment: I wish there were such isArrayOf function in Swift ...