# How to check if an argument is a lambda

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I am processing a collection of instances of `MyCustomType` as follows:

```
fun runAll(vararg commands: MyCustomType){
    commands.forEach { it.myMethod() }
}
```

Besides instances of `MyCustomType`, I'd like to pass and process lambdas of type `() -> Unit`, something like this:

```
fun runAll(vararg commands: Any){
    for(command in commands){
        if (command is MyCustomType){
            command.myMethod()
        } else
        if(command is () -> Unit){
            command.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if(command is () -> Unit){` does not compile with the following message: `Cannot check for instance of erased type: () -> Unit`.

Is there a way to check if an object is `() -> Unit` at runtime?

I have seen [another answer that recommends using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154463/how-can-i-check-for-generic-type-in-kotlin). I do not think that is relevant: my code does not use generics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check for generic type in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154463/how-can-i-check-for-generic-type-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin is going to compile your lambda into an instance of `Function0`. If you know this, you can use a `when` block to compare and smart cast quite nicely:

```
fun runAll(vararg commands: Any) {
    commands.forEach {
        when(it) {
            is Function0<*> -> it.invoke()
            is MyCustomType -> it.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

And then to call it:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runAll(
        MyCustomType(), 
        { println("Lambda!") }
    )
}
```

**Warning**: The downside of this approach is that with type erasure, you don't know if you're getting a `Function0<Unit>` or a `Function0<Int>`, because the type isn't available at runtime for you to make that determination. That means somebody could give you a lambda that returns something and you would ignore the results.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why your `MyCustomType` isn't a `Function0` by itself?
If it would be, you could just use a `vararg commands : () -> Unit` and you could then just call `command()` regardless on what is passed (which is by the way the same as calling `command.invoke()`). You can do that even now with your current code:

Change signature for `runAll` to:

```
fun runAll(vararg commands: () -> Unit) { ...
```

Then call it using:

```
runAll(MyCustomType()::myMethod, { println("self-built-function") } /*, ... */)
```

or the same written a bit differently with its own val:

```
val customObj = MyCustomType()
runAll({ customObj.myMethod() }, { println("self-built-function") })
```

Moreover, if you require all commands to have a certain return value you can do so still, e.g. just use `vararg commands: () -> String` if all your commands must return a `String`.

Using `Any` in that regard may lead to headaches in the future. If you narrow down your type, you are at least sure that you will always have commands behaving in the same way. Moreover you get the best code completion support that way. With `Any` you can pass anything, but it doesn't `run` everything.

If you only want to check whether a parameter is a lambda, you can also use the following:

```
someObj is Function<*>
```

However you can't call `invoke` then without casting it to a specific function type, i.e.: `Function0`, `Function1`, etc.
Regarding `Function0`, etc. Todd already answered that. But as he also mentioned in his warning: there is a downside to that. I can only recommend omitting `Any` whenever you can.

Comment: Makes sense. Will definitely do that.